# Should I stick to LINQ in this simple case?

Tags: linq

Consider:

```
            float[] xPos = new float[pt3f.Count];
            float[] yPos = new float[pt3f.Count];
            float[] zPos = new float[pt3f.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < pt3f.Count; i++)
            {
                xPos[i] = pt3f[i].X;
                yPos[i] = pt3f[i].Y;
                zPos[i] = pt3f[i].Z;
            }
```

I know I can use LINQ here

```
                var xPos = pt3f.Select(I => I.X).ToArray();
                var yPos = pt3f.Select(I => I.Y).ToArray();
                var zPos = pt3f.Select(I => I.Z).ToArray();
```

so my questions is apart from a much cleaner code using LINQ, are there any performance benefits?

I think in terms of performance, using a single for-loop is faster, am I right i.e. 3 Linqs will be eventually converted to 3 loops.

Comment: No, on the contrary you loose performances in this case. Not really a big problem at the end but you should measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the LINQ example will result in three loops instead of just the one in your first example. But in most practical cases, you won't notice any difference, at least not on small arrays.

Unless you actually notice a performance problem, I personally would prefer the more readable LINQ version.

Comment: Most versions of linq will also be slower if it was just one loop because the `Select()` has lost the information to create the array at the correct size and has to incrementally grow and then trim at the end. (.NET Core has an optimisation for this case and will start with the array at the correct size, though it still has some extra overheads over the other approach). This is another reason why if performance was key the linq approach *might* be too slow, but as you say it's better to stay with the more readable until it's proven insufficient.

Comment: @JonHanna Very interesting the part about the optimization... I didn't trust you so I went to check it :-) (and I saw that you are working on that part of code :-)... So I was getting the information directly from the horse's mouth :-) )

Comment: @xanatos that particular case was optimised before I even knew .NET Core had been opened up, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/872bb70953bcfe0a47dcc6e9789fbd330e295bc3 so while I've tweaked those paths further since, I'm not quite the horse in question :)